# webpack's eslint and babel settings relation to .eslintrc and .babelrc

Tags: webpack, settings, eslint, babel-loader

What is relation between `webpack's` settings for `eslint` and `babel` loader, and their corresponding files `.eslintrc` and `.babelrc`?

For example, in webpack I have:

```
rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    include: paths.SRC,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                }
```

with no options passed, does it mean I should define options in `.babelrc` file? And if I don't create `.babelrc` file, I should pass `presets` and `plugins` to `babel-loader` directly in `webpack` as following (same for eslint):

```
use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'env', 'react'],
          plugins: ['transform-es2015-destructuring', 
          'transform-object-rest-spread', 
          'transform-class-properties'
          ],
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

> with no options passed, does it mean I should define options in
>   .babelrc file?

Yes, otherwise babel won't know what to apply.

> And if I don't create .babelrc file, I should pass presets and
>   plugins to babel-loader directly in webpack as following (same for
>   eslint):

Passing presets and plugins via options the same as creating a `.babelrc` file.

The same logic applies to eslint as well.

Comment: so, creating a .babelrc would be preferred, because it's options are kept in one place only, as both eslint and webpack (and babel ;-) use it from there, right?